# IO From sockets is hanging

Tags: java, sockets, java-stream

So I am trying to pass some text between 2 machines and have those classes:

The peer class simply holds a socket.

NetworkHelper:

```
public class NetworkHelper
{
    private NetworkHelper() {}

    public static Socket writeLineToPeer(Peer peer, String message) throws IOException
    {
        Socket socket = peer.getSocket();
        
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        
        writer.println(message);
        
        return socket;
    }
}
```

```
public class ServerConnectionThread implements Callable<Void>
{
    private Peer peer;

    public ServerConnectionThread(Peer peer)
    {
        this.peer = peer;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws InvalidMessageException, IOException
    {
        String message = "";

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.peer.getSocket().getInputStream()));
            
        message = reader.readLine();
            
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Once a `ServerConnectionThread` is launched from the server (working perfectly fine) the thread just hangs at the `reader.readLine()` in the `call()` method.
I've tried using all kinds of streams, with line delimiter (\n), without line delimiter, but they all just either get stuck on the read method or continues without reading anything (I am sure that I'm sending a message).

EDIT: The client sends a message simply by writing:

```
NetworkHelper.writerLineToPeer(peer, "Hello world");
```

EDIT 2: The handshake is ok: https://pasteboard.co/JuxLX7c.png

Comment: Are you sure the message is transferred? I would advice to check with Wireshark on the receiving end to see if the socket connection (handshake ect) is made correctly.

Comment: The socket should be connected since if I terminate the program on either side, the other side gets a connection reset. @SnowmanXL

Comment: @nos The 'true' on the constructor means auto flush, anyway I've already tried it and it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Generally, when you are writing network software, you should not use constructs that use the local default character encoding. Define a particular encoding for the communication and ensure that both sides use it.

Comment: @Holger I've now tried using UTF-8 for both sides and still nothing

Comment: @SnowmanXL https://pasteboard.co/JuxLX7c.png

Comment: That does not show that any data is actually transferred. Also, are you sure _peer_ refers to the socket for the accepted connection?